# Mysql: comparing tinyint column with varchar value

Tags: mysql, sql

I was looking into some code and some bug caught my eye. Someone compared tinyint column with varchar value.

But surprisingly this is working (as intention was to compare with numeric value 0).

**Sample Query:**

```
 create table t1(x1 tinyint);

 insert into t1 values (0),(0), (1), (2);

 select * from t1 where x1 = 'live'
```

**Result:**

```
x1

0

0
```

[Sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c2e3f/1)

My question is why (any) varchar value behaves the same way as numeric value 0 for int/tinyint column?

Comment: If you need to compare a varchar column with a int/tinyint column, there's probably something wrong with you db design.

Comment: Please read... a bug caught my eye..

Comment: Sorry, didn't read carefully enough, again...

Comment: @jarlh A use case when you may need to compare a `varchar` value with a column of arbitrary type is a general "search" field, which searches all columns to contain a given value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MySQL silently converts strings to numbers, in a numeric context.

It does so by converting leading digit-like characters to a number.  If there are no digits, the value is 0.

So, this is equivalent to `x1 = 0`, because of this conversion.

Comment: encounter this today, very weird behavior. I expect an error or at least show an empty result

Comment: @LuqmanSungkar . . . You will get an error if you use `cast()`.  Implicit conversion does not generate an error -- sometimes this is convenient.